# Howto apply texture to an object

Tags: texturing

I was generating objects using rock generator and after I was trying to apply a texture....

(used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5YNJghc81U)

And it looks weird..... prolly a reason but doesn't look like the texture I selected...

Texture (or a lowered detail one for this forum):

[image]

And when applying it to my stone object it looks like this:

[image]

Should be an easy fix.... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you exactly followed your tutorial, it should work, but only if you have correctly UV unwrapped your mesh.

Comment: That is a very poor tutorial for proper UV unwrapping. I'm not surprised it gives those results on a random shaped object like a rock especially one with lots of subdiv and displacement modifiers on it! You'd really need to get the shape of your rock as you want it and then apply all the modifiers before UV unwrapping it. That's really outside the remit of this Q&A forum.

Comment: I'm trying to create rocks for an old game, so detail and low polycount is prefered. But seems hard to put a simple texture on an object........ is it 2022 or 1996?

Comment: please pack the image and share your file so that we see where's the problem

Comment: Umm I'm new to blender....... how do I pack an image?

Comment: https://lasseedsvik.se/random/stones.blend

Comment: File > External Data > Pack Resources. Then see [this](https://blend-exchange.com/help) for instructions to upload the Blend file.

Comment: and where would I upload it to?

Comment: really hard making a simple rock in blender it seems

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted in my last posting (behind 'this' in the instructions sentence)! https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: was i unclear about posting link 
www.lasseedsvik.se/random/stones.blend?